# Property is less accessible than property

Tags: c#

I have build this class to accept information from web service.

So I have this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;

namespace WSOmniacare.Models.AAHome
{
    /**
    * Author:           Michele Castriotta
    * Description:      data transfer object (DTO) that includes a subset of properties of ImageSecSoc
    * 
    **/
    public enum VoltiType
    { // Name of the enum is NodeType
        BLOBS, FACES
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ImmaginiSecSocDTO
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "image")]
        public string image { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "image_width")]
        public int image_width { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "image_height")]
        public int image_height { get; set; }

       /* [DataMember(Name = "enum")]
        public VoltiType volti { get; set; } */

        [DataMember(Name = "rectangles")]
        public IEnumerable<Rectangle> Rectangles { get; set; }

        [DataContract(Name = "rectangle")]
        public class Rectangle
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "n_rects")]
            public int n_rects { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Name = "rects")]
            public IEnumerable<Rect> rects { get; set; }

            [DataContract(Name = "rect")]
            public class Rect
            {
                [DataMember(Name = "x")]
                public int x { get; set; }

                [DataMember(Name = "y")]
                public int y { get; set; }

                [DataMember(Name = "width")]
                public int width { get; set; }

                [DataMember(Name = "height")]
                public int height { get; set; }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

But I have this error

[image]

Comment: Did you implement `VoltiType` twice?

Comment: Compiles fine for me. Are you sure `VoltiType` is public in your code, and it is not part of a class that is not public? Remeber that if you don't set it to public it will be set to internal by default

Comment: I tried to copy your code and it compiles correctly to me. Can you post the Entire Class? Thank you.

Comment: I have copy entire my class in the edit section

Comment: The posted code works for me. Can you select the `VolitType` and press F12 to see what class is actually referenced (then make sure it’s public)? Also, try to clean and rebuild your solution.

Comment: Please include your actual code, or create a [mcve]. As your compiler error shows, the type is in the `[unreadable].DTO` namespace, which is not the case in the code you show.